# Yet another google scholar preprint bug question

Tags: google-scholar, preprint

I published a paper two months ago in JPR (publisher is ACS). Before the submission, I put the paper on biorvix with the same title. Now I am stuck with the preprint on google scholar and even searching by DOI returns the preprint instead of the published paper. Is this the infamous preprint bug in action? I was under the impression that was not crawling the correct source but in my case the DOI of the published paper returns the preprint?

Comment: bioRxiv has a "Now published in" field that you can put the publication data in. There is no guarantee that it will make google scholar accept the published version as the "main" one (this still hasn't happened with a paper of mine from 2016 posted on the arXiv), but at least everyone clicking the link will see that your preprint has been published.

Comment: I wouldn't waste much time or worry on this problem. Do the things that are easy (keep your own CV up to date; add publication data to your bioRxiv preprints) and let the world figure out the rest. Everyone in academia by now understands that google is all heuristics and search results are not meant to be a point of truth.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Well said. That's the best answer to most questions on this site about Google Scholar.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, and this is an annoying bug! (which I have been affected by as well)
A possible workaround that I applied is to create a manual entry for your published paper and then merge it with the preprinted entry. GS will then ask you to choose which entry you want to be displayed on the page, go with the published one of course.
The link will then direct you to the bioaRxiv page, and there hopefully you already have the link to the published paper. It's not ideal, but better than nothing...